# How to share java models between microservices in microservice architecture

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices

I am designing the architecture of my new app.I chose microservice architecture.In my architecture I noticed that I have models that are used by diffrent microservices. I want to know if  there is a way to share models code between microservices instaed of writing them in each microservice.

By the way I am using the spring boot framework for my app.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should only be sharing models that define the API of your micro-service e.g. Protobuff `.proto` files or the Java classes generated from them.

This is normally done by creating either a separate project or converting your micro-service projects into a multi-module projects where one of the modules is a thin API module with interface definition.

There is nothing wrong in sharing code between micro-services but you have to be careful. Share too much internal implementation details and you end up with a [distributed monolith instead of micro-services](https://blog.newrelic.com/engineering/distributed-monolith-vs-microservices/).

Answer (score 11):

You can create a separate project with common models, create a jar of this project and add dependency of this jar in other microservices.

But I have a practical experience, its a nightmare to maintain this common project, because for every change you have to create a new version and update the build scripts of all the microservices.

In my opinion we should not share models among the microservices.

Comment: Iknow im late to this discussion. But if you would decide to not use a seperate project to handle all the models and you decide to reuse each model in every microservice then you end up with the same problem. When a model changes you have to change all the model files form each microservice which will be more work in the end then just update the dependencies for each microservice.

Comment: @RutgerdeGroen You are right. I was thinking the same. Let me know a right way if you have found out to share the Models. Ex: Response list from a micorservice APIs, to be used by another microservice FeignClient.. Dont think creating the model again in new microservice is good idea.

Comment: I ended up creating a private npm package with all the models needed to be shared between services. For instance I created an REST API and a GraphQL microservice both using the same data models. They both acces the models through one npm package. This way you manage all the models in one place, you only have to update the dependencies ones in a while.

Answer (score 8):

In a Microservices architecture, each one is absolutely independent of the others and it must hide the details of the internal implementation.

If you share the model you are coupling microservices and lose one of the greatest advantages in which each team can develop its microservice without restrictions and the need of knowing how evolve others microservices. Remember that you can even use different languages in each one, this would be difficult if you start to couple microservices.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/290922/shared-domain-model-between-different-microservices

Comment: Well, microservices (normally) need to communicate with each other, so you *have* to expose an api at least, and with that api comes a model

Comment: @Lino If you are specifically looking for POJO, please package it as a jar and use that in the micro-service.

Comment: @MebinJoe this is exactly what I was thinking. Basically one could have an auth-service, which contains an `Account`-POJO, which in turn is provided in a common module, which can be utilized by another microservice. However: the authors of the microservice, which uses the auth-service, might decide to implement its own POJOs or other structures, which will be used to map the JSON-response to a class or w/e the consuming service needs.

Answer (score 3):

If you are draconian about this decision you will run into unsatisfactory conditions one way or the other. It depends on your SDLC and team dynamics. At Ipswitch, we have many services that all collaborate and there are highly shared concepts like device and monitor. Having each service have its own model for those would be unsustainable. We did that in one case and the translation just created extra work and introduced inconsistency defects. But that whole system is built together and by one large dev team. So sharing makes the most sense there. But for an enterprise, where you have multiple teams and multiple SDLCs across microservices, it makes more sense to isolate the models to avoid coupling. Even then, however, a set of closely collaborating services that are managed by a given team can certainly share a model if the team accepts the risk/benefit of doing so. There is nothing wrong with that beyond academics and philosophy.

So in short, share minimally but also avoid unnecessary work for your team.

Answer (score 1):

You could move your model classes to a different project/repository and add it as a dependency to your microservices that need to share it.

Comment: If you do that, you'll create a coupling between two microservices, and actually could end up with monolithic application that just mimics microservices.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if your microservices use Swagger, but, you can use [Swagger Codegen](https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-codegen/) to generate your models.

For example, If you have UserService which accepts and/or returns User object. The consumer of UserService can use the Swagger Codegen plugin to auto-generate the User class at build time.

You can use Swagger Codengen maven or gradle plugin pretty easily.