# How to share JPA entity across multiple spring boot applications

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

We would like to share the **Employee** across both applications exposed as micro services. But **Employee** has the JPA definition, how do we package this is as a separate jar which can be shared across multiple applications

**Spring Boot "AppA" has following entity**

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "employees")
public class Employee {

}
```

**Spring Boot "AppB" fetches Employee from "AppA"**

```
ResponseEntity<Employee[]> response =
  restTemplate.getForEntity(
  "http://localhost:8080/employees/",
  Employee[].class);
Employee[] employees = response.getBody();
```

Comment: Why do you do microservices when you strongly couple both services with the entity?

Comment: do you use Maven and configure the packages via pom.xml?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli its intentional and this is one of the places where the entity needs to be shared

Comment: @FelixSchildmann we use gradle for build + deploy

Comment: You could use XML to map the entity will be free of annotations

Comment: @SimonMartinelli If a project has multiple microservices, there is some level of sharing which happens across few entities which cannot be avoided. Just trying to understand what the best practices are over here

Comment: If the microservices are cut well, for example, in the meaning of bounded contexts of DDD there is no sharing of entities.

Comment: Probably related question: [How to share java models between microservices in microservice architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55394469/how-to-share-java-models-between-microservices-in-microservice-architecture)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to share java models between microservices in microservice architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55394469/how-to-share-java-models-between-microservices-in-microservice-architecture)

Comment: What you are looking for are transfer objects which do not depend on a database like JPA entities. Then map your JPA entity to a transfer objects before sending it back to the caller. While im not a fan at all of sharing POJOs between apps, you can put these POJOs in a separate maven app, that would publish a new version everytime a change is done so that you can use it in your apps. Nowadays I use OpenAPI contracts for those use cases and using the contract, I can generate the transfer objects.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. In micro services, usually thare are 2 modules: sdk and server in one service while sdk can be shared to other services.  Mostly sdk contains  pure java object, and you have to create DTOs in sdk, and copy properties from entity. I really hate this way, as most DTOs have the same properties with Entities.    So far I haven't found any goog solutions for this.

Answer (score 3):

> You have to wrap the Entity first in a `Record` and then use
> `Corba-SCNR` version 3 to access it from the other service.
>
> Alternatively, you might want to rethink your
> microservice-architecture, as its not good to have two services access
> the same entity/database.

Ok, trolling time is over.

To answer your question: you cannot share an Entity over REST between two services in a way that is still giving you the guarantees defined by JPA/Hibernate.
Why is that? Because the `EntityManager` in JPA/Hibernate creates a wrapper around the Java Object you have, intercepts calls to it and kind of remembers when you change some fields so it knows which sql statements to generate when you "flush" the changes to the database. These wrappers cannot be serialised over your REST Endpoints, at least not in a way that another service could pick them up and continue where the first service stopped.

In general, it is a bad idea to directly expose your JPA Entities in your REST Controllers. I personally prefer to create small DTOs ( Data Transfer Object ) that I fill with the data that I need to expose and only expose those in the REST endpoints.

So best would be to think about "which information does AppB need from the Employee" and put theses in the DTO, then expose them in the Controller of AppA.
If you need to make changes to the Employee in AppB, create a controller in AppA that accepts requests from AppB and then send a request from AppB to AppA.

Depending on the size of the `EmployeeDTO` you create, you could put it into a shared jar or simply copy it over. Depending on the size of your project, you could also describe it in Swagger/OpenAPI in AppA and generate it in AppB, but this might be overkill.

I hope this helps a bit. Sorry for the trolling before.

Answer (score 3):

If you really need to share them and do not want to copy and paste you can achieve that by packaging your shared entities and repos on a separate Spring project (without an Application.java) and declaring that project in your downstream services as maven/gradle dependency.

Let's say you've put the entities and repos in a separate library under the following packages:
Under a package like *my.common.lib.entities*, *my.common.lib.repos*

You can make Spring discover them on your downstream services AppA and AppB by using *@ComponentScan* typically on your corresponding Spring Application classes:

AppA:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"my.common.lib.entities", "my.common.lib.repos"})
@SpringBootApplication
ApplicationAppA {


}
```