# JPA Entity Data foregin key

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, entity, postgresql-9.3

I have data model in microservices A which will be referenced in the microservice B .How to share the model from A to B.

Will it work with sharing the entity as library to microservice B

Comment: Yes. The data will be passed back and forth, so the library with the model representing that data can be shared. Just be careful about versioning it and compatibilities should it change that they won't break one side or the other if they aren't all on the same version.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give some example on sharing the data

Comment: Examples of REST or other direct communication? There are tutorials for that. Though you can just as easily use a shared library for data models in the two services that access the same central database to pass data.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to create such coupling between 2 microservices.
Either:

- if it is a natural coupling (implied by the business domain) the 2 microsservices might be better if they were merged together as a single microservice.
- the "A entity" that is used inside "B microservice" is actually representing another role/concept based on the same real world domain object. As such, it should be represented by another entity, extracting strictly the properties and behaviours that are relevant to this role.

Comment: But i have master microservice which is to create master records like city state country. Second microservice is transaction service which needs master as one to many relationship. How this can be created in the second microservice entities

Comment: Ok, seems like a "shared kernel" (https://vaadin.com/blog/ddd-part-1-strategic-domain-driven-design#_shared_kernel), right? Instead of exposing your JPA entities directly, you should use DTOs with the relevant shared properties of those entities, then share the library containing the DTOs. I found this other answer that might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73662710/how-to-share-jpa-entity-across-multiple-spring-boot-applications. Beware of the distributed monolith! :)